# Node JS Routing request

Tags: node.js

In server.js for specifying routing which is best method from below?
Method 1:

```
app.use('/', loginrouter);
app.use('/', logorouter);
app.use('/', headermenurouter);
app.use('/', hometaglinerouter);
app.use('/', howweworkrouter);
```

and then in each router file specify route

Method 2:

```
app.use('/login', loginrouter);
app.use('/logo', logorouter);
app.use('/headermenu', headermenurouter);
app.use('/hometagline', hometaglinerouter);
app.use('/howwework', howweworkrouter);
```

and then specifying route according to it in each seperate route file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sole reason to choosing a different router is the requested URI, go with option 2.

Comment: can you please explain more